# Trimming text to a given pixel width in SVG

Tags: svg

I'm drawing text labels in SVG. I have a fixed width available (say 200px). When the text is too long, how can I trim it ?

The ideal solution would also add ellipsis (...) where the text is cut. But I can also live without it.

Comment: What SVG engine are you targetting? Adobe? WebKit? Firefox? IE9?

Comment: It's for a web application, so I'm targeting WebKit, Firefox, IE9.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a [textPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextPathElement) element, since all characters that fall off the path will be clipped away automatically. See the text-path [examples](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/test/harness/htmlObjectApproved/text-path-02-b.html) from the SVG testsuite.

Another way is to use CSS3 [text-overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#text-overflow0) on svg text elements, an example [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/css/text-overflow-ellipsis.svg). Opera 11 supports that, but you'll likely find that the other browsers support it only on html elements at this time.

You can also measure the text strings and insert the ellipsis yourself with script, I'd suggest using the [getSubStringLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getSubStringLength) method on the text element, increasing the nchars parameter until you find a length that is suitable.

Comment: The CSS3 example is not working for me. Neither the text-overflow or the text path seem to clip the overflow. Has anything changed?

Comment: @DavidMeza sadly 'text-overflow' (still) isn't supported inside svg text elements, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=366550

Comment: @ErikDahlström Thank you, the first method worked great! I fiddled with it a bit as on my first attempt wasn't using quite unique values in the `xlink:href` - `id` associations.

Comment: Just note that for `textPath[xlink:href]` to work on a document with a `base[href]`, you'll need to use an absolute href to the path

Answer (score 36):

Using d3 library

a wrapper function for overflowing text:

```
    function wrap() {
        var self = d3.select(this),
            textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
            text = self.text();
        while (textLength > (width - 2 * padding) && text.length > 0) {
            text = text.slice(0, -1);
            self.text(text + '...');
            textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
text.append('tspan').text(function(d) { return d.name; }).each(wrap);
```

Comment: The question does not mention d3.

Comment: ... but  it helps for people who got here with the same problem, and using d3 :)

Comment: You should put that answer into a Gist or something so you can [copy paste](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27723752/279259) it faster next time.

Answer (score 18):

Implementing Erik's 3rd suggestion I came up with something like this:

```
//places textString in textObj, adds an ellipsis if text can't fit in width
function placeTextWithEllipsis(textObj,textString,width){
    textObj.textContent=textString;

    //ellipsis is needed
    if (textObj.getSubStringLength(0,textString.length)>=width){
        for (var x=textString.length-3;x>0;x-=3){
            if (textObj.getSubStringLength(0,x)<=width){
                textObj.textContent=textString.substring(0,x)+"...";
                return;
            }
        }
        textObj.textContent="..."; //can't place at all
    }
}
```

Seems to do the trick :)

Comment: This worked for me, but you have to make sure the node is already rendered in the dom. So beware when dynamically add nodes.

Comment: @borisrorsvort actually I encountered the same problem. Have you come up with a solution for running this on non-rendered nodes?

Comment: At the end of the classical update function I loop all the nodes then using your function. Then when new nodes comes in I rerun the update method. https://gist.github.com/borisrorsvort/cc6ada7e4cbfc7f959b9

Answer (score 6):

@user2846569 show me how to do it ( yes, using d3.js ). But, I have to make some little changes to work:

```
         function wrap( d ) {
                var self = d3.select(this),
                    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
                    text = self.text();
                while ( ( textLength > self.attr('width') )&& text.length > 0) {
                    text = text.slice(0, -1);
                    self.text(text + '...');
                    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
                }
            }
            svg.append('text')
                .append('tspan')
                .text(function(d) { return d; }) 
                .attr('width', 200 )
                .each( wrap );
```

Comment: @user2846569's solution has function vars that don't exist. Use this modified solution instead.

Answer (score 4):

The [linearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient) element can be used to produce a pure SVG solution.  This example fades out the truncated text (no ellipsis):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" x2="200" y1="0" y2="0" id="truncateText">
      <stop offset="90%" stop-opacity="1" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="truncateLegendText0" gradientTransform="translate(0)" xlink:href="#truncateText" />
    <linearGradient id="truncateLegendText1" gradientTransform="translate(200)" xlink:href="#truncateText" />
  </defs>

  <text fill="url(#truncateLegendText0)" font-size="50" x="0" y="50">0123456789</text>
  <text fill="url(#truncateLegendText1)" font-size="50" x="200" y="150">0123456789</text>
  
</svg>
```

(I had to use linear gradients to solve this because the SVG renderer I was using does not support the textPath solution.)

Comment: This worked better than any JS options as I was using Angular. Angular was interferring and causing a horrible infinite loop flicker of truncated and full text

Answer (score 3):

Try this one, I use this function in my chart library:

```
function textEllipsis(el, text, width) {
  if (typeof el.getSubStringLength !== "undefined") {
    el.textContent = text;
    var len = text.length;
    while (el.getSubStringLength(0, len--) > width) {}
    el.textContent = text.slice(0, len) + "...";
  } else if (typeof el.getComputedTextLength !== "undefined") {
    while (el.getComputedTextLength() > width) {
      text = text.slice(0,-1);
      el.textContent = text + "...";
    }
  } else {
    // the last fallback
    while (el.getBBox().width > width) {
      text = text.slice(0,-1);
      // we need to update the textContent to update the boundary width
      el.textContent = text + "...";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: changed a lot, but the original snippet is this one.

Answer (score 1):

My approach was similar to OpherV's, but I tried doing this using JQuery

```js
function getWidthOfText(text, fontSize, fontFamily) {
    var span = $('<span></span>');
    span.css({
       'font-family': fontFamily,
        'font-size' : fontSize
    }).text(text);
    $('body').append(span);
    var w = span.width();
    span.remove();
    return w;
}

function getStringForSize(text, size, fontSize, fontFamily) {
    var curSize = getWidthOfText(text, fontSize, fontFamily);
    if(curSize > size)
    {
        var curText = text.substring(0,text.length-5) + '...';
        return getStringForSize(curText, size, fontSize, fontFamily);
    }
    else
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now when calling `getStringForSize('asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf', 110, '13px','OpenSans-Light')` you'll get "asdfasdfasdfasd..."

Answer (score 1):

There is several variants using d3 and loops for search smaller text that fit. This can be achieved without loops and it work faster. textNode - d3 node.

```
clipText(textNode, maxWidth, postfix) {
        const textWidth = textNode.getComputedTextLength();       
        if (textWidth > maxWidth) {
            let text = textNode.textContent;
            const newLength = Math.round(text.length * (1 - (textWidth - maxWidth) / textWidth));
            text = text.substring(0, newLength);
            textNode.textContent = text.trim() + postfix;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work in general, because characters can have different widths. In this case the reduced length cannot be obtained via proportional scaling. It is a good alternative though for mono-spaced fonts.

Comment: @bluenote10, you're right, but I think difference in 1-2-3 symbols are not principal in most cases. For example I use it to trim too long titles (more than 30 symbols) on chart. I start with solution that use loop, but it add noticeable delay in chart update, if I have a lot of titles (normal situation for my application). I think speed is more important than accuracy in javascript applications in most cases.

Comment: For symbols yes, but what if the string contains a total of 10 IIIIIIIIII vs 10 WWWWWWWWWW? It simply depends on the use case. If your designer wants all strings to be as close in length as possible you have to measure the text. Also note that you can internally cache these string length measurements, which will give excellent performance in many situations as well.

Comment: @bluenote10, you're fully right, but I think you describe rare situations, in most cases functions like this used for regular text. Anyway you describe disadvantages of my method, this help if anybody try to use it, thank you.