# Text-overflow is not working

Tags: css, svg

Please check the below sample svg code. I have used text-overflow property in text element. But, the property behavior is not working properly.

```
<svg width="180" height="120" viewBox="0 0 180 120">
<style>
  text { font: 16px sans-serif; }
  rect { fill: none; stroke: black; vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; stroke-width: 1; }
</style>

<g>
<rect x="19.5" y="16.5" width="100" height="20"/>
<text x="20" y="2em" width="100">SVG is awesome</text>
</g>

<g transform="translate(0,30)">
<rect x="19.5" y="16.5" width="100" height="20"/>
<text x="20" y="2em" width="100" text-overflow="clip">SVG is awesome</text>
</g>

<g transform="translate(0,60)">
<rect x="19.5" y="16.5" width="100" height="20"/>
<text x="20" y="2em" width="100" text-overflow="ellipsis">SVG is awesome</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Is SVG-text element support text-overflow property ? How can i use this property in svg element ?

Thanks.

Comment: [Might not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute#T).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add ellipses to overflowing text in SVG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975440/add-ellipses-to-overflowing-text-in-svg)

Answer (score 2):

text-overflow is not part of the current SVG 1.1. standard.

A new SVG 2 specification is in progress and [text-overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextOverflowProcessing) is scheduled to be included in that. UAs are beginning to implement SVG 2 but only Opera 12 has implemented text overflow thus far.

In the meantime you could perhaps include the text as html via foreignObject as html text does support text-overflow.

Comment: foreignObject is not supporter in any version of ie sadly, so I would not recommend it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh834675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @borisrorsvort OK, so what is **your** answer?

Comment: I don't know yet, i'm also searching. I was just indicating the compatiblity issue about text-overflow.

I had some hope that the last solution of OpherV on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241315/trimming-text-to-a-given-pixel-width-in-svg would work. But I haven't managed to make it work yet.